# Data is automatically deleted from MySQL Database in every 24 hours

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

I have a shared hosting at Hostgator.com.

Every morning at 8:24am my database is automatically removing all the users and moving data from one column to another.

I have to restore my backup in every morning to fix this but now I am pissed off. Is there any automated script that is running at a fix time in every 24 hours in my PHPMyAdmin or in my MySQL Database? How do I find it out and how do I remove it? Or is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: either a cron job or scheduled event, trigger, etc. could be anything

Comment: What do you mean by "moving Data from one column to another" ?

Comment: First I thought Code Guard of Hostgator is taking backup and restoring it in every 24 hours. As they don't take backup of the email accounts associated with the domain name, I thought the users were deleted for this reason. I have cancelled the Code Guard from my Customer Portal but nothing happened.

Comment: Basically "Moving Data" means:
I have a "Car List" and a "Deleted Cars" Section. Every morning atlease 135 cars are deleted from Car List to Deleted Cars. But they are not totally deleted from my Database. 

That's why I said data is moving from one column/section to another.

Comment: Review your database privileges (grants) and users.

Comment: And review if you have any "triggers" causing this "move"

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Hostgator for this.
Either this is their service for you to move to more paid offer plan or some hacking event going on. PhpMyAdmin doesn't do stuff like this. Mysql have pretty few tools for automated tasks like this. So, maybe try another db hosting service!

Comment: I have talked to Hostgator. They said everything is running fine from their end. 

But I have the same database in another hosting of Go Daddy. Everything is fine there.

Comment: Still in every morning at 8:20AM all my users are automatically deleted from the Database. I don't understand why this is happening. There are no cron jobs or any kind of triggers in the database. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Have you reviewed Website accesslogs in that time of the day?